Injection Token Renamed When Importing Angular Library
I have created a test library (NgxTest) using ng-packagr, which makes use of the APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER injection token:
import { APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER, ComponentRef, NgModule } from "@angular/core";

@NgModule()
export class NgxTest { 
    static forRoot() {
        console.log(APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER)
        return {
            ngModule: NgxTest,
            providers: [{
                provide: APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER,
                useFactory: async (c: ComponentRef<any>) => {},
                multi: true,
              }]
        };
    }
}

However, I'm encountering an issue when I import this library into an Angular project.
In my project, I load the library’s configuration using importProvidersFrom(NgxTest.forRoot()) in my app.config.ts:
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { NgxTest } from 'ngx-test';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), 
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(NgxTest.forRoot()),
  ]
};


For some reason, when the library module is imported this way, the APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER injection token gets renamed from InjectionToken to InjectionToken2, which causes it not to be executed during bootstrapping.

bundled library should not bundle the token itself into it, but rather it should contain import from angular/core that will then be handled by a dependant app bundler

As far as I can tell, the token is purely imported from @angular/core (see library code)

checked the bundled version. is the token still coming from external import?

Within both .mjs files (esm/fesm) the APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER is imported from @angular/core directly.

Instead of forRoot pattern could you try a function, that return the providers instead. Make sure you have this function exported in the public-api.ts, so that it can be imported in the main application.
export const provideNgxTestBootstrap = (): EnvironmentProviders => {
  const providers: (Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[] = [
    {
      provide: APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER,
      useFactory: async (c: ComponentRef<any>) => {},
      multi: true,
    },
  ];

  return makeEnvironmentProviders(providers);
};

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { NgxTest, provideNgxTestBootstrap } from 'ngx-test';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), 
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(NgxTest.forRoot()),
    provideNgxTestBootstrap(),
  ]
};

Reference Answer

Yeah, I saw this pattern in the router module, however, this still results in the InjectionToken2 beeing created.
One sidenode: When I import the module/bootstrapProvider directly everything works fine. But when I bundle them into an esm module the InjectionToken class is beeing renamed.

@Usche Then it might  not be possible to use APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER and APP_INITIALIZER from a library, it can work only for the items inside the library, but not for an application that uses the library

It seems to be possible for @angular/router which does the exact same thing, but I cannot pinpoint the difference.

@Usche try implementing the bootstrap listener the same way as the angular router source codeprovide_router.ts and try checking
